# i'm 23 years,high school dropout ,looking for a second chance

Tags: graduate-school, education

i'm from morocco,23 years old,dropped out of high school and i got into freelancing,but now i want to go back to school (school based in canada or europe "overseas"). which type of programs would suit my case ? any advice would be helpful

Comment: Sorry, undergraduate admissions is out of the scope of this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With rare exceptions, you probably need to get a [secondary education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_education) diploma by some means. In the US there are programs and exams for older students to complete their secondary education, called [GED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Educational_Development).

From there, the path is about like any other student. Apply for some educational program that meets your needs and make your best case for being a success at it.

To do this otherwise might be possible, but difficult. It would involve convincing some university, or at least some faculty member, that you have the necessary background without the usual diploma. Rare, but not impossible.

Comment: thank you for the answer
do you have any list of schools i can contact to check what i need to enroll for a GED ?